# Android: Pass string array from values to .java

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, arrays

I am using this code to pull my string array from my values folder:

```
String achievementNames[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.achieveString);
    String achievementDescriptions[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.achieveDescript);
```

However, when I run this, it gives me a null pointer exception on those lines of code. Is there a better way to pull string arrays or is there an error in my code?

Comment: Where you placed that statement? in Declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call `getResources()` unless `onCreate()` callback has been triggered.

```
public class StackStackActivity extends Activity 
{

    String[] myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.glenns); // This returns null

    public StackStackActivity()
    {

        myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.glenns); // This returns null also
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.glenns); // Returns an array from resources
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for identifying what is most likely the source of OP's problem. However, it should be clarified that there's no need to call `setContentView` before retrieving resources. In fact, sometimes there are reasons to defer any calls to `setContentView` until after `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass a `Context` object to wherever you call this method from (as my guess is that `getResources()` is returning `null`). With this `Context` object, you can call,

```
context.getResources().getStringArray(...);
```

Comment: Yeah... post more information. i.e. the code that surrounds those two lines, the logcat, the line number where the `NullPointerException` occurs, etc. There's not much left to tell from the info you've given us.